# Chaining Hadoop MapReduce 1.1.1 Example

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm very much a Hadoop beginner, but in Hadoop 1.1.1, I'm trying to do map -> reduce -> map -> reduce.  I'm having a difficult time finding a concrete example of how to do this in Java.  I'm really curious what the whole driver method would look like.  I'm currently using the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` libraries (which I believe is the newest codebase).

Also, I'd prefer not to install another library like Oozie if I don't have to.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to trigger a mapper after the reduce function and then trigger a reducer for the last mapper again? If yes, why so? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Expressions_Galore Yes, I think so.  From what I've read it's common to have to multiple mappers and reducers, it's just not obvious to me how to do this.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122832/hadoop-mapreduce-possible-to-define-two-mappers-and-reducers-in-one-hadoop-job

Comment: No, he had 2 independent mapreduce jobs.  Mine are dependant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may help you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/03/29/how-to-chain-multiple-mapreduce-jobs-in-hadoop.aspx

You may also look into ChainMapper(http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/ChainMapper.html) depending on what you are trying to achieve. This works only with one reduce, though. If you want to go specifically map -> reduce -> map -> reduce, I would go with my first link.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you.  Some of the JobConf references are part of the old API.  But, doing new Job(), waitingForCompletion, then new Job() again worked fine.